# Android Programming: Quiz Questions Not Working

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android quiz application. I have three .java files for this program: TrueFalse.java, QuizActivity.java, and Quiz.java, all of which work together to run the application.

The problem I am having is that I am trying to show the user's score when the quiz is done. My code is not doing that.

This is my TrueFalse.java code:

```
package com.example.quiz;

public class TrueFalse {

public static final int NO_ANSWER = 1;
public static final int TRUE_ANSWER = 2;
public static final int FALSE_ANSWER = 3;

private int mQuestion;
private boolean mTrueQuestion;
private int mUserAnswer;

public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion){
    mQuestion = question;
    mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
    mUserAnswer = NO_ANSWER;
}

public boolean getAnswerRight() {
    switch (mUserAnswer){
        case TRUE_ANSWER:
            return mTrueQuestion;
        case FALSE_ANSWER:
            return !mTrueQuestion;
    }
    return false;
}

public void setAnswer(boolean answer) {
    mUserAnswer = answer ? TRUE_ANSWER : FALSE_ANSWER; 
}

public boolean isQuestionAnswered(){
    return mUserAnswer != NO_ANSWER;
}

public int getQuestion(){
    return mQuestion;
}
}
```

This is my QuizActivity.java code:

```
    package com.example.quiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mPreButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Button mQuitButton;
    private TextView mMessage;
    private Quiz mQuiz=new Quiz(new TrueFalse[]{
        new TrueFalse(R.string.message, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.message2, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.message3, true)
    });

    private int mCurrentQuestion = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_box);
        mPreButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pre_button);
        mNextButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mQuitButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.quit_button);

        mMessage.setText(mQuiz.getQuestions()[mCurrentQuestion].getQuestion());

        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                showAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                showAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mPreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                QuizActivity.this.mQuiz.preButton();
                updateButtonVisibility();
                QuizActivity.this.mMessage.setText(QuizActivity.this.mQuiz.getCurrentQuestion().getQuestion());
            }
        });

        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                QuizActivity.this.mQuiz.nextButton();
                updateButtonVisibility();
                QuizActivity.this.mMessage.setText(QuizActivity.this.mQuiz.getCurrentQuestion().getQuestion());
            }
        });
        mQuitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
            }
        });
     }      

        public void updateButtonVisibility(){
            if (mQuiz.getCurrentQuestion().isQuestionAnswered()){
                mTrueButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mFalseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    mTrueButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mFalseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

        }

        private void showAnswer(boolean userChoice){
            mQuiz.getCurrentQuestion().setAnswer(userChoice);
            Toast.makeText(this, mQuiz.getCurrentQuestion().getAnswerRight() ? R.string.toast_correct : R.string.toast_incorrect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            updateButtonVisibility();

            if(mQuiz.areQuestionsLeft() == false){
            /*If I set the above line's false to true, I get a score right after
              the user answers the first question.*/
                mNextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mPreButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mMessage.setText("Your score is: " + mQuiz.getScore());
            }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And this is my Quiz.java code:

```
package com.example.quiz;

public class Quiz {
    private TrueFalse[] mQuestions;
    private int currentQuestion;

    public Quiz (TrueFalse[] questions){
        setQuestions(questions);
        currentQuestion = 0;
    }

    public TrueFalse[] getQuestions() {
        return mQuestions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(TrueFalse[] questions) {
        mQuestions = questions;
    }

    public boolean nextButton(){
        if (currentQuestion < mQuestions.length-1){
            currentQuestion++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean preButton(){
        if (currentQuestion > 0){
            currentQuestion--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public TrueFalse getCurrentQuestion(){
        return mQuestions[currentQuestion];
    }

    public boolean areQuestionsLeft(){
        for (TrueFalse question: mQuestions)
        {
            if (question.isQuestionAnswered())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return getScore(0);
    }

    public int getScore(int bonus){
        for(TrueFalse question: mQuestions)
            bonus += question.getAnswerRight() ? 1 : 0;
        return bonus;
    }
}
```

In the QuizActivity.java code, I have a showAnswer function, in which I am showing the score. This uses an areQuestionsLeft function from the Quiz.java code to loop through and send a boolean value, and that same function uses an isQuestionAnswered function from the TrueFalse.java code.

One thing I can see is that in my Quiz.java code, in the areQuestionsLeft function, the value inside the for loop is ALWAYS returned.

If someone can point out where my error is, I will greatly appreciate it!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: You get error or your score always zero?

Comment: On the application, the score doesn't even show up when it should (after the last question is answered.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I just wanted to compliment you on your code cleanliness. I'm on Stack a fair bit and don't tend to read most people's horrid mess of a lazy attempt at coding, but your's I enjoyed.

I found this:

```
public boolean areQuestionsLeft(){
    for (TrueFalse question: mQuestions)
    {
        if (question.isQuestionAnswered())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which will return true every single time, as long as:

1. There is at least 1 question in mQuestions
2. The first question has been answered (either true or false)

This is because you're actually *returning as true* from `areQuestionsLeft()` rather than *counting* the number of questions that have/haven't been answered.

Hope that helps!